# Mongodb - Group by Array element

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to group my JSON data using the element inside array.
I think `db.collection.aggregate` will work. But I need to write custom function (reduce function) instead of built-in aggregation operators/expressions. Any suggestions?

Sample data:

```
{
    "name" : "Person Name",
    "age" : 50,
    "expense" : [
        {
            "category" : "food",
            "date" : "2017-01-01",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "category" : "travel",
            "date" : "2017-01-02",
            "amount" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

My code:

```
db.collection.group({ 
    key: { "expense.category": 1 },
    initial: { total : 0 },
    reduce: function( curr, result ) {
        result.total += curr.amount;
    }
})
```

where, `key: { "expense.category": 1 }` does not work for me.

Comment: Can you show an expected result?

Comment: Expected result is { food: 100, travel: 200 }. Sum of amount should be based on number of array elements.